# Unreachable statement in c

Tags: c, function, return-value

I am now learning C programming language and try to understand the functions. 
The code below does not give error in Visual Studio and returns the first argument sent to that function. 
I think it should give an error but it does not.

How does the given code work and how to return the first argument which is 3 in the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int hesapla(int x, int y);
void f();
int main()
{
int a, b, sonuyc; 
int s; 
printf("\n");

printf("sonuc = %d", hesapla(3, 10));
system("pause");
return 0;
}
int hesapla( int x, int y) {

    if (x > y )

        return y; 


    if (x == y)

        return y + 1;  

}
```

Thank you..

Comment: `I think it should give an error but it does not.`...why so?

Comment: Return value is not determined when `x < y`.

Comment: your function never returns `x`. You need to add a condition to do that.

Comment: I think this is undefined behavior. An error message is not required. Compilers can't always determine that there is a possible code path that leads to falling off a function without using `return` properly.

Comment: When we send the first argument bigger than the the second to the function, the if conditions in the function will not be true, so return statement will be unreachable because of that i think it should give error.  How to decide which value to return back in that condition?

Comment: @Barmar Yes they can. It's mathematically verifiable.

Comment: @nicomp It's equivalent to the Halting Problem.

Comment: In Visual C++ 2015 it issues the warning:  `warning C4715: 'hesapla': not all control paths return a value`.  This is not the same as "unreachable code" mentioned in the title - all the code is reachable. A function with multiple returns is a bad idea in any case, and this issue illustrates one reason for that (there are others).

Answer (score 1):

Your function `hesalpha` does not `return` anything when `x < y` , therefore, it exhibits *undefined behaviour* .

Either you can handle this case with an `if else` or just `return` a value as *default when both the previous conditions are false* .

Answer (score 0):

Toy need to ensure that all pathes explicitly return a value, otherwise you'll get whatever happens to be left in whatever register is used to return values from a function which is non-deterministic.

```
int hesapla( int x, int y) 
{
    if (x > y )
        return y; 

    if (x == y)
        return y + 1;  

    return x ;
}
```

Though for your own sanity when your code becomes more complex, and to avoid the issue altogether I suggest:

```
int hesapla( int x, int y) 
{ 
    int ret = x ;

    if (x > y )
    {
        ret = y; 
    }
    else if(x == y)
    {
        ret = y + 1;  
    }

    return ret ;
}
```

For simple functions such as this, it is possible to return the result in a single expression thus:

```
int hesapla( int x, int y) 
{ 
    return (x > y) ? y : (x == y) ? y + 1 : x ;
}
```

Succinct perhaps, but I am not sure I'd recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Neither if-statement is true, so `hesapla ()` will return `0`, the default return value for `int` functions.

It's unclear exactly what you're trying to do, but maybe you're after this?

```
int
hesapla (int x, int y)
{
    if (x == y) {
        return y + 1;
    }

    if (x > y) {
        return y;
    }

    return x;
}
```

Though, this this better...

```
int
hesapla (int x, int y)
{
    if (x == y) {
        return x + 1;
    }

    return min (x, y);
}
```